# camera matrix differs from given example in ROS

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi   everybody
I am using  Logitech and  I got  camra calibrated results

```
camera matrix
512.674949 0.000000   315.382678
0.000000   510.413978 205.677427
0.000000   0.000000   1.000000

projection
511.625946       0.000000       313.445886   0.000000
0.000000         511.368134     204.690908   0.000000
0.000000         0.000000       1.000000     0.000000

distortion
0.047498 -0.123536 -0.000940 -0.002017 0.0000
```

board  size : 15 by 11 and square 70 mm or 0.007 m
Could  any body  tell me  that  results  is acceptable  with this parameters.

Best
Taher

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229345/camera-matrix-differs-from-given-example-in-ros/) by [btaher20](https://answers.ros.org/users/25814/btaher20/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Of course it differs, even if you use two similar cameras the result would probably be slightly different. Those values describe

- The properties of the lens mounted on the camera
- The pixel size on the CMOS sensor and the offset of the central point

It is impossible to say if the results are acceptable or not, the only thing you can do is to check the reprojection error showed by your calibration program (the smaller the better) and to take a look at the undistorted image. Try to point your camera at straight lines in the real world (in the ceiling or floor for example), they should still appear as straight lines in your undistorted image and the distortion observed on the raw image should have been rectified.

And those values seem to be normal values, nothing weird.

Read [this introduction](http://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/14/decompose/) for a better understanding of your camera.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-17**:
We considered a reprojection error of below 0.5 (half a pixel) as acceptable when calibrating cameras on the PR2 at Willow Garage.